# Expression have must a constant value in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am asking why in this case i should have a constant value in A[size] , but i can't find the answer.

```
int size;
    cout << "Enter number of elements";
    cin >> size;

    int A[size];

    cout << sizeof A << endl;
```

Comment: The size of an array must be a compile-time constant, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) for example.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard